# Sys.Databases ANSI Settings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ansi-sql

With ANSI setting in SQL Server generally being handled on a connection by connection basis, does anyone know what purpose the ANSI settings in sys.databases serve?

- is_ansi_nulls_on
- is_ansi_padding_on
- is_ansi_warnings_on
- is_ansi_null_default_on
- is_concat_null_yields_null_on
- Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database settings are used only when the API or session does not specify the settings. Modern drivers like SqlClient, ODBC, OLE DB, etc set these options ON automatically by default, although they can be later toggled as needed. Legacy APIs (e.g. DB-LIB) do not specify the settings at all so the database ON setting is used in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can still set those settings at database level too:

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE ANSI_NULLS_ON;
GO
ALTER DATABASE ANSI_NULLS_ON SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
CREATE DATABASE ANSI_NULLS_OFF;
GO
ALTER DATABASE ANSI_NULLS_OFF SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
GO
SELECT is_ansi_nulls_on
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] IN (N'ANSI_NULLS_ON',N'ANSI_NULLS_OFF');
GO
```

Though, the connection's/server's settings do appear to override the database setting as the below returns `0` for both:

```
USE ANSI_NULLS_ON;
GO
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ANSI_NULLS_ON;
GO
USE ANSI_NULLS_OFF;
GO
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ANSI_NULLS_ON;
GO
```

If you were using a contained database, however, then this may be different ( have no tested at this time).

Comment: Thank you!! Appreciate the help!